# blank page when saving extension settings

Tags: control-panel, error, extension, settings

I am developing an EE extension and everything was working fine and I thought I was done.  So I uninstalled the extension and re-installed it to testing everything.  It uninstalled fine and re-installed fine but now when I submit the settings in the control panel I get a blank white page with no error of any kind.

I have looked at the apache error log and there is nothing is the error log.  I have installed it on a clean install of EE and same thing. Anyone have any suggestions on how to track the problem down?

Answer (score 1):

I finally tracked this down and posting my findings here so in case anyone else runs into this issue.

I have a custom settings for my extension and in the settings_form.php file there is this line of code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?=$name?>" />
```

Apparently at some point I deleted a character out of the name field so it was fil instead of file like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="fil" value="<?=$name?>" />
```

And this caused the blank page when saving the extension settings.  In the file system/expressionengine/controllers/cp/addons_extensions.php in thew function save_extension_settings in fails this check

```
if ($this->input->get_post('file') === FALSE OR ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9][\w.-]*$/i",$this->input->get_post('file')))
```

It returns false and you get the blank white page.  Shouldn't this show some kind of error message instead?  Seems like a bug in EE to me.